# Разрешить загрузку файлов только с расширением .zip или .rar

Tags: php

Приветствую.

Нашел скрипт загрузки файлов на сервер. Скрипт работает, но он является "дырой" в моем сайте, потому что кто-то может загрузить на мой сайт файл delete.php (допустим), где будет скрипт, с помощью которого удалятся все папки сайта.

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы  можно было загружать файлы формата только .zip или .rar?
Пробовал другие скрипты встроить в этот, но не получилось. А именно пробовал запретить некоторые типы, но на сервер все-равно загрузили файл с обфускацией  в формате или .PhP или .php (не помню точно), а потом и просто .php начали загружать.

Так вот. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было загружать файлы **только** с расширением .zip или .rar?

Тот код, что есть сейчас, который не разрешает загружать файлы с некоторыми расширениями:

```
<?php 
        // ini_set('display_errors','Off');
        function getFileCount($path){ 
          $last = 0;
          if(substr($path, -1) != "/") $path = $path."/";
          $dir = scandir($path);
          foreach($dir as $name)
          {
            if($name != '.' && $name != '..')
            {
              $file_name = explode('.', $name)[0];
              $ex = explode("_", $file_name);
              end($ex);
              $n = $ex[key($ex)];
              $count[$n] = $name;
              ksort($count);
              end($count);
              $last = key($count);
              $last += 1; 
            }
          }
          return $last;
        }
        $uploaddir = '/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/files/upl/';
        $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name'])[1]; 
        $ext = strtolower($ext);
        if(in_array($ext, ['php', 'html', 'xml', 'jar', 'PhP', 'phP', 'pHp', 'Php', 'PHp', 'pHP'], true))
        die('Нельзя загружать файлы такого типа!');
        $file_name = basename(str_ireplace(' ', '_', $_FILES['userfile']['name']), '.'.$ext).'_'.getFileCount($uploaddir).'.'.$ext; // Нумеруем файл
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file_name;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
          echo 'Файл загружен <br>  ';
        } else {
          echo "Файл не загружен ";
        }
        $proto = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http"; 
        // На всякий случай добавил определение протокола
        $link = $proto.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/files/upl/'.$file_name; 
        // Ссылка на загруженный файл
        echo "<a href='".$link."' class='btn btn-primary ok'> Посмотреть/скачать</a>
        Ссылка: 
        <input class='form-control' id='exampleInputEmail1' value='".$link."' onfocus='this.select()' style='width: 200px;'>
        <br> 
        ";
        ?>
```

Comment: Мне советовали mime-тип проверять, но я не знаю как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ext = explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name'])[1];` подразумевает что в имени файла есть только 1 точка, а их может быть много. Вам нужна часть после последней точки.

```
$file_name_parts = explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$ext = $file_name_parts[count($file_name_parts) - 1];
$ext = mb_strtolower($ext);
//потом проверяем окончание файла
if(!in_array($ext, ['zip', 'rar'], true))
die('Нельзя загружать файлы такого типа!');
```

**EDIT**
поменял `strtolower` на `mb_strtolower` т.к. надо пользовться `mb_*` вариантами функций если есть шанс, что строка будет в юникоде.

**EDIT2** хотя для расширения файла это не важно :)

Answer (score 1):

ну если "в лоб", проверять только по расширению - то у вас же есть в коде место, где проверяется тип файла... только там "черный список" (вот это нельзя, остальное можно)... поменяйте логику на "белый список" (вот это можно, остальное нельзя), и будет вам счастье... ну по-крайней мере, половина счастья...

```
 if(!in_array($ext, ['zip', 'rar'], true))
        die('Нельзя загружать файлы никакого типа кроме ZIP/RAR');
```

для второй половины счастья - да, проверяйте МИМЕ. см. [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: Знаете, это было первым, что я попробовал. =)
Но, к сожалению не работало. В вашем комментарии я увидел ! (логическое запрещение) и понял почему у меня не работало. Спасибо! Тогда я забыл ! перед in_array поставить.